# How to make a uniform indent for a list of parameter as the following?

Tags: indentation

I want to make a list of parameters, where the name of the parameter is on the left, and the parameters are on the right-hand side but is on the same indent for each line (exactly like the following pic.).

[image]

But the result that I got is LaTex skipped all of the space between the parameters' name and ":" sign (see the next pic).

[image]

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code resulting in your shown screenshot in your question ...

Comment: Hi..This is the script (actually the question screenshot with black background is taken from the script itself). Please see at the updated pic.

Answer (score 1):

In LaTeX, by default, white space in the input file counts only as a single space, which is why multiple spaces act only as a simple space.

You can use a `tabular` environment for this.  I also tweaked spacings before units. (For those who prefer the use of the `siunitx` package to format unit-ed quantities, Zarko notes in a comment how to achieve that for the current case.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Slope height &: 4\,m \\
Slope inclination &: 1:2 (26.57\,deg.)\\
Layer thickness &: 4\,m ; 4\,m\\
Unit weight &: 16\,kN/m$^3$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you soo much! :)

Comment: For units is sensible to use `siunitx` package. Using it the last table row is: `Unit weight &: \qty{16}{kN/m^3}` or better `Unit weight &: \qty{16}{\kilo\newton\per\cubic\metre}` or the same but with `\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}` in preamble.